# AngularJS leave page

Tags: angularjs, sockjs

I use AngualrJS for my frontend, before navigating to a page in my **routes.js** there is a **resolve** where I can initialize variables needed for controller.

Actually I need the oposite of them - if I leave a page than a method should be invoked, because I use websocket/sockjs and I will switch of the ping if chat page is leaved.

Is there any possibility to do this?

Thanks a lot!

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myProject.chat')
    .controller('ChatController', ChatController);

ChatController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$location', '$http', '$timeout', ...];

function ChatController($scope, $state, $location, $http, $timeout, ...) {
    $scope.vm = this; 
    var vm = this;


vm.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/chat/' ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `destroy` event you can use

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
  // do cleanup
});
```